# How to convert CSV to nested JSON(upto level 3) in Python

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I'm having the following data in CSV format.

```
id,category,sub_category,sub_category_type,count
0,fruits,citrus,lemon,30
1,fruits,citrus,lemon,40
2,fruits,citrus,lemon,50
3,fruits,citrus,grapefruit,20
4,fruits,citrus,orange,40
5,fruits,citrus,orange,10
6,fruits,berries,blueberry,20
7,fruits,berries,strawberry,50
8,fruits,berries,strawberry,90
9,fruits,berries,cranberry,70
10,fruits,berries,raspberry,16
11,fruits,berries,raspberry,80
12,fruits,dried fruit,raisins,10
13,fruits,dried fruit,dates,15
14,fruits,dried fruit,dates,10
15,vegetables,legumes,beans,12
16,vegetables,legumes,beans,15
17,vegetables,legumes,chickpea,12
18,vegetables,green leaf,spinach,18
19,vegetables,green leaf,cress,19
```

I want to convert the above CSV format to nested JSON as pandas.DataFrame.to_json() donesn't help me in converting to nested JSON format.

Is there any solution for this?

PS: I'm answering the above question in Q&A style to share the knowledge. I would be happy to know if there is any other solution better than this.

Comment: Why are you answering your own question immediately upon asking it.  Your response should form part of your original question.

Comment: then can you explain how am I supposed to answer this question? When i click the check box **Answer your own questions - share your knowlwdge Q&A style**, it opens up a text box to post the answer. If my response should be the part of my question, then why there has to be another text box to post the answer?

Comment: Alternatively, your response could be something that you have tried (which should be part of the question), but for which you are seeking a better solution for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is inspired from [this](https://github.com/andrewheekin/csv2flare.json/blob/master/csv2flare.json.py) github link. This code will help us in converting CSV upto level 3 nested JSON

```
import pandas as pd
import json


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# choose columns to keep, in the desired nested json hierarchical order
df = df[["category", "sub_category","sub_category_type", "count"]]

# order in the groupby here matters, it determines the json nesting
# the groupby call makes a pandas series by grouping "category", "sub_category" and"sub_category_type", 
#while summing the numerical column 'count'
df1 = df.groupby(["category", "sub_category","sub_category_type"])['count'].sum()
df1 = df1.reset_index()

print df1

d = dict()
d = {"name":"stock", "children": []}

for line in df1.values:
    category = line[0]
    sub_category = line[1]
    sub_category_type = line[2]
    count = line[3]

    # make a list of keys
    category_list = []
    for item in d['children']:
        category_list.append(item['name'])

    # if 'category' is NOT category_list, append it
    if not category in category_list:
        d['children'].append({"name":category, "children":[{"name":sub_category, "children":[{"name": sub_category_type, "count" : count}]}]})

    # if 'category' IS in category_list, add a new child to it
    else:
        sub_list = []        
        for item in d['children'][category_list.index(category)]['children']:
            sub_list.append(item['name'])
        print sub_list

        if not sub_category in sub_list:
            d['children'][category_list.index(category)]['children'].append({"name":sub_category, "children":[{"name": sub_category_type, "count" : count}]})
        else:
            d['children'][category_list.index(category)]['children'][sub_list.index(sub_category)]['children'].append({"name": sub_category_type, "count" : count})


print json.dumps(d)
```

On execution,

```
{
"name": "stock", 
"children": [
    {"name": "fruits",
    "children": [
        {"name": "berries", 
        "children": [
            {"count": 20, "name": "blueberry"}, 
            {"count": 70, "name": "cranberry"}, 
            {"count": 96, "name": "raspberry"}, 
            {"count": 140, "name": "strawberry"}]
        },
        {"name": "citrus", 
        "children": [
            {"count": 20, "name": "grapefruit"},
            {"count": 120, "name": "lemon"},
            {"count": 50, "name": "orange"}]
        }, 
        {"name": "dried fruit",
        "children": [
            {"count": 25, "name": "dates"}, 
            {"count": 10, "name": "raisins"}]
        }]
    },
    {"name": "vegtables",
    "children": [
        {"name": "green leaf",
        "children": [
            {"count": 19, "name": "cress"},
            {"count": 18, "name": "spinach"}]
        },
        {
        "name": "legumes",
        "children": [
            {"count": 27, "name": "beans"},
            {"count": 12, "name": "chickpea"}]
        }]
    }]
}
```